# Gradlew doesn't add dependencies to my external libraries(class path) in IDEA 16.2

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew, gradle-dependencies

tl;dr; adding adding dependencies to build.gradle downloads it fine but doesn't add it to the classpath/external libraries in idea.

Hi guys

Im new to developing webapps in java, and im trying to depend on a few jars on mvnrepository.com, the only time the dependencies are downloaded into the external libraries and added to the classpath is when i import the project as a gradle project, as in, each time i have a project up and running and i add a new dependency i would have to import the whole project into intellij again.

my build.gradle file looks like this:

```
group 'project_name'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice
 compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '3.0'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core
 compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-core', version: '9.0.0.M9'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core
 compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-core', version: '1.19.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json
 compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-json', version: '1.19.1'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client
 compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '2.23.2'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet
 compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-servlet', version: '1.19.1'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server
 compile group: 'com.sun.jersey', name: 'jersey-server', version: '1.19.1'




 testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}



task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.5'
}
```

When i add a new dependency to the list, and run ./gradlew build, with or without the --refresh-dependencies option it does download the new dependencies but it doesn't add the downloaded files to the external libraries/classpath so i can't import them into the java code. I saw a question similar to this one, where they accepted answers like running:

```
./gradlew idea
```

In my case this doesn't help at all, it just adds some autogenerated files in the directory with no clear difference to behavior.

Then they accepted importing the project as a gradle project aswell, which i have done - which works, but adding new dependencies doesn't work.

FYI I am using the gradle 2.5 wrapper and IDEA community 16.2

Comment: After you run `./gradlew idea` IDEA should tell you to reload the project

Comment: Im not going to run  `./gradlew idea` because it generates annoying files... and obviously they dont make a difference when i can just run it through the interface. Thanks for the suggestion, maybe it does work :)

Comment: What annoying files? It should only generate the files you need for IDEA to open the project

Comment: <name_of_project>.iml, <name_of_project>.ipr, <name_of_project>.iws ... it looks like copies of the gradle.build file, just in XML and obviously 3 different flavours.

Comment: These are your IDEA project files.  This perhaps explains why your IDEA didn't pick up your changes.  After you run `./gradlew idea`, also run `open <name_of_project>.ipr` <--- this is the IDEA project file that Gradle just generated

Comment: Well right now the project runs just fine, i can add dependencies, run the program just fine etc. So im not gonna jinx it, spent too much time on bugs today :) but maybe il check it out, thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. I solved/figured it out, Apparently it didn't help to just run build, 
inside of intellij i had to go to View --> Tool Windows --> Gradle, it then opens the gradle window, where i could click the refresh button, which downloads the dependencies.

Thanks to anyone who looked it over :)